# Fetching Facebook "likes" data from a user's profile using old rest api

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to fetch the "likes" data from a user's profile using the old rest api ? Specifically FB has launched this new  "Likes" feature recently, where a user can Like a page, etc. This information is visible under the "interests and likes" section of the Info page of a user. I am looking for a way to fetch this information using the old rest api. Is there a field in user.getInfo that I can query on that will return this information ?

Comment: Why would you want to use the old API?  Even if it's supported now, it'll probably be deprecated soon.

Comment: The new API is still in a state of development - Facebook recommends that for the time being you use the old API.

Comment: u can use fql

'SELECT name,type FROM page WHERE page_id IN \
                   (SELECT target_id  FROM connection WHERE source_id=%i and target_type="Page") \
                   AND type!="APPLICATION"'%(friend.fb_uid))

Although it works for my users but not my friends

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: Nooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

Getting a users likes is not possible using the old REST API. You can continue making all your existing API calls using the old API, and just use the graph for likes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Graph API to do this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user -- basically fetching `/me/likes`. It's much more natural than our older API. If you need advanced use, then you can query the `page_fan` FQL table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan.